# The finite extensions of $SL_2(q)$

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group such that $Z(G)\leq SL_2(q) \leq G $ and $G/Z(G) \cong PGL_2(q)$· Is there any information about the structure of $G$?

Comment: ${\rm GL}_2(q)$ does not satisfy the condition $Z(G) \le {\rm SL}_2(q)$  when $q>3$.

Comment: Yes.. I should say that a subgroup of $GL_2(q)$. I am editting it Thank you

Comment: This changes nothing, your assumptions force equality of the cardinals. Derek means that the inclusion $Z(G)\le SL_2(q)$ fails for $GL_2(q)$. Anyway, this post is not research level and should be posted in a more appropriate forum.

Comment: My main goal is to find the structure of such $G$

Comment: For odd $q$ there are two isomorphism classes of groups $G$ that contain ${\rm SL}_2(q)$ as a subgroup of index $2$, and for which $G/Z(G) \cong {\rm PGL}_2(q)$.

Comment: What are these two isomorphism classes?

Comment: For odd $q$, ${\rm PGL}_2(q)$ has Schur multiplier of order $2$, and there are two isomorphism classes of covering groups. It is difficult to come up with more concrete descriptions. The situation is similar for the symmetric groups $S_n$.